# Thunderbird Addon for New Mail Notification

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am using Thunderbird 12.0.1. at my Win7. Is there any addon for Thunderbird as like gmail notifier that will alert me with a pop-up at bottom-right screen. If I close Thunderbird I want it to work at system tray and warn me at new messages with a summary?

Comment: This question is off topic on Stack Overflow, the questions here are [supposed to relate to programming](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). If you don't exactly want to develop this extension yourself you should be asking on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Thats why I flagged my own question as off topic. No need to down vote.

Comment: @Kamaci Is there a problem with either of the answers provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Minimize_to_system_tray_%28Thunderbird%29) is what I use, works fine... (Mimize to system tray add-on).

Edit: This should really be in SU, as it has nothing at all to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Thunderbird has already built-in new message notification feature.
A new message alert appears on my Win7 with the subject and mail body.

If you mean 'When I close Thunderbird' by completely exiting the application, I don't think it is possible to keep receiving notifications when the app is not running.

If you are on Mac, you may try [Growl Notifications add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/growl-new-message-notification/) for Thunderbird

Comment: Does it makes notification without making any configuration for thunderbird?

Comment: Tools -> Options / **When a new message arrive** -> **Show an alert** is this checked?